# android Volley does not response when request again

Tags: android, android-volley

all.
I am using volley to make a http request to my website server.  And it works fine and response when click the commit button to add a request to request queue. But click the button again does not response. It still shows the progressdialog and response nothing. Is there something wrong ?

Here's code example below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String URL = "http://www.google.com";

public RequestQueue mQueue = null;
public StringRequest request = null;

private Button mScanButton = null;
private TextView mDisplay = null;

private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);



    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("Response retrieved");
                    mDisplay.setText(response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mDisplay.setText("That didn't work.");
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    request.setShouldCache(false);

    mScanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Mapping data", "please wait..");

            mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            mQueue.add(request);
            System.out.println("Add to queue..");
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399305/how-to-get-json-response/31420858#31420858) May this guide you here is the complete source which helps you understand easily.

looking at this line

```
if (ServerConfig.isNetworkOnline(SplashScreen.this)) {
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "your server link", serverResponse, errorListener) {
        };
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(strReq);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your network connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

you can remove those above code leaving with below code.

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "your server link", serverResponse, errorListener) {
            };
            AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(strReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to move the area of request declaration to on-click method and it works fine. But I still don't understand how it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String URL = "http://www.google.com";

public RequestQueue mQueue = null;
public StringRequest request = null;

private Button mScanButton = null;
private TextView mDisplay = null;

private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

    mScanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Mapping data", "please wait..");

            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("Response retrieved");
                    mDisplay.setText(response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mDisplay.setText("That didn't work.");
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            mQueue.add(request);
            System.out.println("Add to queue..");
        }
    });

}
```